# Gestures and Responder Chain

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Im developing an ipad application. And i have a outer scroll view and inner scroll views. Inside the inner scroll views im using a grid view to render my items. Im using a library for this called GMGridView.

and in the grid view im using gestures. (ex: pan gesture). The gridviews are added as subviews to the outer scroll view. So if my understanding of the responder chain is correct, first the super view should respond and then the subviews. But now wat happens is wen i touch on the gridview the control immediately goes to the gridview.

Any idea as to why this is happening? Basically what i want to be done is the outer scroll view to be scrolled before the control goes to the inner scroll view which is a vertical scrol view.

It'll be great if anyone can help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Gesture recognizers don't participate in responder chain, see here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html